# How to connect two cities by a line on Python Folium using shortest path

Tags: python, folium

I want to illustrate a line between Tokyo and Hawaii using the Folium mapping module with Python. How do I program this code so that the line takes the logical, shortest path from these two cities by crossing over the pacific ocean and not going through the entire geography of the world like it's doing in the picture below?
Current code:

```
import folium

tokyo = (35.6895, 139.6917)
maui = (20.7967, -156.3319)

# Calculate the midpoint
midpoint = ((tokyo[0] + maui[0]) / 2, (tokyo[1] + maui[1]) / 2)

# Create a map centered around the midpoint
m = folium.Map(location=midpoint, zoom_start=2)

# Draw a line connecting Tokyo and Maui
folium.PolyLine(
    locations=[tokyo, maui],
    color='green',
    weight=2
).add_to(m)

# Add markers for Tokyo and Maui
folium.Marker(location=tokyo, popup='Tokyo').add_to(m)
folium.Marker(location=maui, popup='Maui').add_to(m)

# Save the map to an HTML file
m.save('path_map.html')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if any of your coordinates has a negative longitude. If so, then add 360 so Folium can interpret the coordinate in the "left" section of the map:

```
import folium

tokyo = (35.6895, 139.6917)
maui = (20.7967, -156.3319)

if maui[1] < 0:
    maui = (maui[0], maui[1] + 360)

# Calculate the midpoint
midpoint = ((tokyo[0] + maui[0]) / 2, (tokyo[1] + maui[1]) / 2)

# Create a map centered around the midpoint
m = folium.Map(location=midpoint, zoom_start=2)

# Draw a line connecting Tokyo and Maui
folium.PolyLine(
    locations=[tokyo, maui],
    color='green',
    weight=2
).add_to(m)

# Add markers for Tokyo and Maui
folium.Marker(location=tokyo, popup='Tokyo').add_to(m)
folium.Marker(location=maui, popup='Maui').add_to(m)

# Save the map to an HTML file
m.save('path_map.html')
```

[image: Folium Map showing the line accross the Pacific]